# How to structure Javascript with Browserify and page specific documentReady functions

Tags: javascript, browserify

I'm working on a NodeJS web project and I'm using browserify as my dependency loader.  For now I have one single file *app.js* where I'm defining all my browser functions, and a grunt process for "browserifing" it into *app-bundle.js*

I'm looking for suggestions for structuring js into different files (not strictly related to browserify).

My idea is to keep using one main js (*app.js* > *app-bundle.js* ) file included in all my pages and inside it I require all the other secondary files (eg *ui.js,common.js, page1.js, page2.js* etc.)

My biggest doubt is about page specific functions, let's say I have a function to initiate an image gallery *initGallery()* that has to be called on documentReady only on one of my pages.

How should I structure my js to call this function just on the page who requires it?

Comment: Why not create page-specific bundles then?

Comment: Because on that case I should have a different <scrip src="..">  on every page. I think it would be great to include just one js bundle for all the site pages.

Comment: It's not very efficient to load unnecessary code into all pages..

Answer (score 0):

You can put the common dependencies in a bundle that exposes them (see `b.require(..., {expose: ...})`) and load that and a script specific to each page. See also `factor-bundle`.

Comment: could you add some more detail to your answer? Maybe with an example